# How to create intermediate step for model one to many association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a simple scenario in Rails. I have a Category model. I have a Product model. The flow is such that User creates a new category, then enters details of each product he wants to add in the category if it is valid then product is eligible to be added in the category. As the user keeps adding product it shows a table of current products that are added in the category. The user can also remove the product from the category. Once he finishes adding all products. he clicks create category, then a new Category and the cat-prod associations are stored in database. How do I create this intermediate step?

Comment: Maybe a single boolean field in `Product#confirmed_category` which indicates if the category was assigned? Is it one-to-many or many-to-many relation, btw?

Comment: It many-to-many relation. The user needs to first have a look at what products he has added in the category like a intermediate step. Then click Confirm then the association between category and products should be stored in the DB in the join table. The user can also discard the process in middle, so I dont want left over categories in the DB

Comment: Then add `confirmed` flag to `ProductCategory` model.

Comment: But if he discards the Category creation in the intermediate step, Maybe just closes his browser.  I have a new category row and multiple associations row left in the DB?

Comment: yes, but they are not confirmed. You can delete them later

Comment: It should be discarded as he has left the process. The user will create a new category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89698/discussion-between-yatish-mehta-and-dimakura).

Comment: Cant you just use the .build method to build them?  Then iterate over the built items.  Save them after they are confirmed.